# javascript - connect two variables

Tags: javascript, variables, connection-string

I have a few (hundred) variables:

```
var image1 = 'xxxx';
var image2 = 'yyyy';
var image3 = 'zzzz';
```

etc...

I'm trying to use a `while` loop to incorporate these images in a function like so:

```
i = 0;
while (i<100) {
    $("#somediv").append(image + i);
    }
```

I understand why this would not work, since first it will look for a variable `image`, then append variable `i` to that.

How can I accomplish this? Naming the variables as an array at first? I'm not too familiar with javascript, and understand PHP moreso. In PHP I could do `function $var($i)` and increment $i++.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of having many separate variables why not just have an array called image and then image1 would be image[0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having individual variables for each image, consider using one array, and iterating that.

```
var images = ['xxxx', 'yyyy', 'zzzz'];

for (var imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < images.length; imageIndex++) {
    $("#somediv").append(images[imageIndex]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an array literal:

```
var images = [
      'xxxx',
      'yyyy',
      'zzzz'
   ],
   somediv = $('#somediv');

for (i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; i += 1) {
   somediv.append(images[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Just what I was looking for / expected!

Comment: @iight Please check it again, I had a typo :)